# Android: How can I know if a Service is running while it was started by AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I need to run a Service in background, while it keeps killed by Android I need to start it again and again. And because of some programming purpose I need to know if the Service is running or not. That is because I will start a second Service at the same time and it keeps starting methods twice.

I've tried this so far:

```
private boolean isServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (NotificationService.class.getName().equals(
                service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But as I read that is only possible when my Service is started with

```
startService(Intent);
```

And because I start my Service with the AlarmManager every 2 minutes for example I don't know how to check if the Service is running. Perhaps if you have an idea how I can avoid the Service starting methods twice and more, I would be satisfied.

Comment: "I need to run a Service in background, while it keeps killed by Android I need to start it again and again" -- ideally, you would not try to have an everlasting service in the first place. "That is because I will start a second Service at the same time and it keeps starting methods twice" -- that should not be possible, as there can only be one running instance of the service.

Comment: I think you need to get alarm id which you sent reciever, is it true ?

Comment: Why do you start your service every two minutes? Couldn't you have long-running service which implements a timed function?

Comment: @Jayp yes I've already tried a long-running service, but after one hour it's killed by Android and I need something that runs in the background "forever", that is why I tried it with AlarmManager so when the service gets killed it will be started again by the alarmmanager

Comment: @CommonsWare you are saying that 2 service of the same kind cannot be started, but I see my methods of the service being executed twice (TimerTask)

Comment: If "my methods" are `onStartCommand()` or things triggered by `onStartCommand()`, that is perfectly normal, as those will get called every time you are calling `startService()`, regardless of whether or not the service is already created and running.

Comment: Try to set the Service as START_STICKY. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
However, if you have to start the service over and over again, you could check if it's running by looping through the running services and checking if your service is found or you override the service's onDestroy method and set a flag, for example to sharedpreferences, which indicates that the service was destroyed. Although, starting a Service again and again seems odd to me as it is suppose to be a long-running background process.

Answer (score 0):

In services 
        `onCreate()` method is called when the service is created for the first time.
you can do all declarations in it.

```
onStartCommand()
```

is called again and again when you try to call it though alarm manager.

If you want that you service does not get killed then you can run the service on a different process.For this you would need Inter Process Communication(IPC).

For doing this you declare the service in the manifest file as follows:

```
<service
    android:name="myservice"
    android:process=":my_process">
<service>
```

the colon(:)my_process in the android:process line tell android system that the name of the process is my_process and the :tells that it is private to the application declaring it.

Reference:[complete tutorial on services](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but the service still gets killed after more than 10 minutes. I've started the service with the android:process=":noti_service", and it works for some minutes and then gets killed. Do I have to add something, so it will run further on?